# where and how are the version numbers given in mercurial using eclipse IDE?

Tags: mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I am using mercurial plugin for eclipse. I am new to version control.

I want to know how the numbers like 0.1, 0.6, 1.8 etc. are given through plugin.

Do we manually give the name while saving the final copy( like "project v1.0")?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse plugins, the version numbers come from the OSGi headers in the MANIFEST.MF.  ex:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 3.7.0.qualifier
```

We set the major.minor.micro version manually based on API versioning guidelines, like http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering

When PDE UI exports this plugin, or PDE build (or another build system) builds it, the build system substitutes something useful for the "qualifier" token in both the MANIFEST.MF and the jar name itself.

For example, org.eclipse.ui_3.7.0.I20110526-0100.jar

Answer (score 0):

It is handled by Mercurial itself.

Yes, you can tag your revisions with meaningful names instead of automatically generated revision numbers.